# Error of adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

After retrieving the list of dates (`StartDate/EndDate`) with the query shown here, I get an error

> Adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow.

Query:

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE(),
        @StartYr DATE,
        @EndOfyr DATE;

DECLARE @DateList TABLE (StartDate VARCHAR(10), EndDate VARCHAR(10));

SET @EndOfyr = DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(@Today) + 1, 05, 10)  
SET @StartYr = DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(@Today), 06, 10)

WHILE @StartYr <= @EndOfyr
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @DateList
    VALUES (@StartYr, @EndOfyr);

    SET @StartYr = DATEADD(yy, -1, @StartYr)
    SET @EndOfyr = DATEADD(yy, -1, @EndOfyr);
END;

SELECT StartDate, EndDate 
FROM @DateList;
```

How can this be solved? Or how to limit the last date to 1900?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I'm just baffled. For starts, why are you storing dates as strings?  Then, what are you trying to do?  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would clarify.

Comment: I will need this list of date for filtering an employee leavedate.

Answer (score 0):

the condition you chose is the same as writing `1=1` because it will always evaluate to true. Please describe what you want to achieve. But to answer your punctual question, change your while condition to :

```
WHILE @StartYr >= '1901-06-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the `while` expression, then add a date comparison:

```
WHILE @StartYr <= @EndOfyr AND @startyr >= '1900-01-01'
-------------------------------^
```

I'm not sure if `@StartYr <= @EndOfyr` is needed . . . and there are certainly other ways of doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a `WHILE` at all? SQL is a set based language and is therefore way better at set based bethods. A Tally would be a far better method to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @StartYear int = 1900,
        @EndYear int = 2020;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@EndYear - @StartYear +1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(T.I + @StartYear,6,10), DATEFROMPARTS(T.I + @StartYear+1,5,10)
FROM Tally T
ORDER BY T.I DESC;
```